# Install xorg-x11-font-utils for opensuse

Tags: xorg, opensuse, fontconfig

how do i install the package xorg-x11-font-utils for opensuse? I need it for microsoft fonts from here https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm but it always complains that iam missing the package xorg-x11-font-utils.

This is the error message it get

```
sudo rpm -i https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        xorg-x11-font-utils is needed by msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch
```

Sadly its not packages for opensuse, so i googled but there are only sites which say its suitable for fedora, centos or rhel.

Does somebody know where i can get it for opensuse tumbleweed

Comment: What release of `openSUSE` are you running?

Comment: Iam using the offical openSUSE Tumbleweed 64bit, VERSION_ID is 20180905

Answer (score 0):

Become `root` and run the following:

```
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/X11:XOrg/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/X11:XOrg.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install font-util
```

That will add the repo for `font-util`, refresh `zypper`, and install it.

Answer (score 0):

SuSE splits up the features that are found in xorg-x11-font-utils (Red Hat) into several packages:

```
mkfontdir, mkfontscale, bdftopcf, fonttosfnt, font-util
```

You may have to install all of those to address the installer's requirements (in a quick read of its script, I see mkfontdir and mkfontscale, and none of the packages appears to depend on the others).

However... that's a **package dependency**.  If you have the pieces installed, you can fool rpm by making a dummy package which "provides" the name xorg-x11-font-utils.  Detailing that's getting into a new question.

Further reading: [*Creating a dummy RPM*](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2006-April/msg00013.html)